# flush network setting after modifying the gateway in registry

Tags: c++, network-programming, gateway

I need to modify the gateway of my network setting. I see there's **DefaultGateway** and **DhcpDefaultGateway** params in registry. Here's my code to change these values:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <string> 

#include <iostream> 
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib") 
using namespace std; 
void GetLanAdapterName( char* szLanAdapterName ); 
BOOL NotifyIPChange( LPCTSTR lpszAdapterName, int nIndex, LPCTSTR pIPAddress, LPCTSTR pNetMask ); 

char szGate[100] = { 0 };
DWORD dwGateType;
char szDhcpGate[100] = { 0 };
DWORD dwDhcpGateType;


BOOL GetRegIP(LPCTSTR lpszAdapterName)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    string strKeyName = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\";
    strKeyName += lpszAdapterName;
    if (::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyName.c_str(), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return FALSE;

    ULONG x = sizeof(szGate);
    auto ret = ::RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "DefaultGateway", 0, &dwGateType, (unsigned char*)szGate, &x);
    x = sizeof(szDhcpGate);
    ret = ::RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "DhcpDefaultGateway", 0, &dwDhcpGateType, (unsigned char*)szDhcpGate, &x);

    ::RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return TRUE;
}
BOOL SetRegIP(LPCTSTR lpszAdapterName, const char* szNewGateway, const char* szNewDhcpGateway)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    string strKeyName = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\";
    strKeyName += lpszAdapterName;
    if (::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyName.c_str(), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return FALSE;
    int x;
    x = strlen(szNewGateway);
    if (x)
        ::RegSetValueEx(hKey, "DefaultGateway", 0, dwGateType, (unsigned char*)szNewGateway, x);
    x = strlen(szNewDhcpGateway);
    if (x)
        ::RegSetValueEx(hKey, "DhcpDefaultGateway", 0, dwDhcpGateType, (unsigned char*)szNewDhcpGateway, x);

    ::RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return TRUE;
}

int main() 
{ 
    char AdapterName[ MAX_PATH ] = ""; 

    GetLanAdapterName( AdapterName ); 

    if (!GetRegIP(AdapterName)) // get adapter
        return 1;
    if (!SetRegIP(AdapterName, "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2")) // change it to some ip that will never work
        return 1;
    //if (!SetRegIP(AdapterName, szGate, szDhcpGate))
        //return 1;


   return 0; 
} 

void GetLanAdapterName(char* szLanAdapterName) 
{     
   HKEY hKey, hSubKey, hNdiIntKey; 
    if( ::RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey ) != ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
        return; 
    DWORD dwIndex = 0; 
    DWORD dwBufSize = 256; 
    DWORD dwDataType; 
    char szSubKey[256]; 
     unsigned char szData[256]; 
    while( ::RegEnumKeyEx( hKey, dwIndex++, szSubKey, &dwBufSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
     {         
      if( ::RegOpenKeyEx( hKey, szSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hSubKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
         {              
         if( ::RegOpenKeyEx( hSubKey, "Ndi\\Interfaces", 0, KEY_READ, &hNdiIntKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )  
          {               
             dwBufSize = 256; 
                if( ::RegQueryValueEx( hNdiIntKey, "LowerRange", 0, &dwDataType, szData, &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
                 { 
                    if( strcmp( (char*)szData, "ethernet" ) == 0 ) // 
                {              
                   dwBufSize = 256; 
                        if( ::RegQueryValueEx( hSubKey, "DriverDesc", 0, &dwDataType, szData, &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
                         {     
                     //  
                      dwBufSize = 256; 
                            if( ::RegQueryValueEx( hSubKey, "NetCfgInstanceID", 0, &dwDataType, szData, &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )  
                      {   

                         strcpy( szLanAdapterName, (const char *)szData ); 
                        break; 
                             } 
                         } 
                     }  
                } 
                 ::RegCloseKey( hNdiIntKey ); 
             }   
          ::RegCloseKey(hSubKey); 
         }   
       dwBufSize = 256; 
     } 
   /* end of while */     

    ::RegCloseKey(hKey); 
}
```

But it's not working, I guess there must be a flush after modifying their registry value. From google I found some similar problem that flushing the dns config, simple as `ipconfig /registerdns`. But how to flush the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can accomplish the same:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96ece1b7-cc88-4675-b036-90197140c9ab/how-to-change-default-gateway-address?forum=csharpgeneral